# phone number displayed as a contact

Tags: contacts

Every few days I see my own phone number listed as a contact. There are several such accounts one below the other. After those then the contacts are listed as normal named contacts. At one time I was able to delete all those unwanted accounts showing only my phone number. Now it tells me I can not delete these accounts from a "read only" contact list. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of those and keep them off my contact list?